# Trying "over partition by" and its not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

This works:

```
select top 100 cti.tradingitemid, pe.pricingDate, pe.priceClose, pe.adjustmentFactor, cc.countryId, cc.companyId
from ciqcompany cc
join ciqfinperiod cfp on cfp.companyid=cc.companyid
join ciqfininstance cfi on cfi.financialperiodid=cfp.financialperiodid
join ciqsecurity cs on cs.companyid = cc.companyid
join ciqtradingitem cti on cti.securityid=cs.securityid 
join ciqPriceEquity pe on pe.tradingItemId=cti.tradingItemId
where pe.pricingDate >= '1974-12-31 00:00:00.000' and pe.pricingDate <'1975-02-01 00:00:00.000' and cc.countryId = 213
order by cc.companyId
```

The problem is that I get hundreds of lines for the same companyID.  I just want one per companyID, the first one would work fine.

I've been looking around and this is the best I could come up with:

```
select *
FROM ( 
        Select  cti.tradingitemid, 
                pe.pricingDate, 
                pe.priceClose, 
                pe.adjustmentFactor, 
                cc.countryId
                Row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY cc.companyId ORDER BY pe.pricingDate) RN
        from ciqcompany cc
                join ciqfinperiod cfp on cfp.companyid=cc.companyid
                join ciqfininstance cfi on cfi.financialperiodid=cfp.financialperiodid
                join ciqsecurity cs on cs.companyid = cc.companyid
                join ciqtradingitem cti on cti.securityid=cs.securityid 
                join ciqPriceEquity pe on pe.tradingItemId=cti.tradingItemId
        where pe.pricingDate >= '1974-12-31 00:00:00.000' and pe.pricingDate <'1975-02-01 00:00:00.000' and cc.countryId = 213
        order by cc.companyId
) 
Where rn = 1
```

The syntax at `Row_number()` is throwing it off, but to me it looks like other examples I see.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?  MySQL one supports it since 8+.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  Not sure?  Am using SQL Server Management Studio 15.0.18118.0.  When I run select @@VERSION I get Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP4) (KB4018073) - 11.0.7001.0 (X64)   Aug 15 2017 10:23:29   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: )

Comment: . . You should tag your question correctly.  I fixed the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work?

```
SELECT *
FROM (
 .....
 ---- missing comma after cc.countryId
 ---- remove order by 
) A
WHERE
   A.RN = 1
ORDER BY cc.companyId
```

Comment: I believe I tried what you recommended and it's not getting past the Row_number() syntax.  In other words, same issue.

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 405
Incorrect syntax near '('.

Comment: missing comma after cc.countryId. thats why

Answer (score 0):

Three things:

- Your subquery needs a table alias.
- The subquery cannot contain `order by`.
- And you need a comma before `row_number()`.

So:

```
select t.*
from ( Select  cti.tradingitemid, 
                pe.pricingDate, 
                pe.priceClose, 
                pe.adjustmentFactor, 
                cc.countryId,
                Row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY cc.companyId ORDER BY pe.pricingDate) RN
        from ciqcompany cc
                join ciqfinperiod cfp on cfp.companyid=cc.companyid
                join ciqfininstance cfi on cfi.financialperiodid=cfp.financialperiodid
                join ciqsecurity cs on cs.companyid = cc.companyid
                join ciqtradingitem cti on cti.securityid=cs.securityid 
                join ciqPriceEquity pe on pe.tradingItemId=cti.tradingItemId
        where pe.pricingDate >= '1974-12-31' and pe.pricingDate < '1975-02-01' and
              cc.countryId = 213
       ) t
order by cc.companyId;
```

I removed the time component from the dates.  It is not needed for the logic.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and still get this error (Line 423 is the Row_number() line):  Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 423
Incorrect syntax near '('.